# Why does sed -i create random files with “q” commands?

Tags: command-line, unix

I’m aware that [BSD sed behaves differently from GNU sed with regards to the `-i` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694228/1968). However, the usual way of using `sed -i ''` on macOS ceases to work when using a `q` command, and I’m wondering whether this is a bug or whether I’m overlooking something in the documentation. In either case, I’d like to know how to restore the expected behaviour for the following simple command:

```bsh
printf foo\\nbar > test
sed -i '' /foo/q test
```

#### Expected output:

```
$ ls -a
.    ..   test
$ cat test
foo
```

#### Actual output:

```
$ ls -a
.            .!79633!test ..           test
$ cat test
foo
bar
$ cat .\!79633\!test
foo
```

In other words: the original file is untouched. The result is instead written to a new, hidden file. The numeric value in the filename changes with every execution and looks like a process ID (it’s in the right range, too). Using `q` without an address gives equivalent behaviour.

Comment: Looks as if sed creates the temporary file with the proper output but quits before it moves the file into place. The following does the same thing as you expect the `i` option to do- `sed /foo/q < test > test.tmp && mv test.tmp test`

Comment: @fd0 Yes, that’s exactly what I’m currently doing. It’s still confusing, and GNU sed behaves differently. So, a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I’ve found confirmation in the commit history: [it’s a bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230507), which was fixed in [r338375](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=338375) in August 2018.